# Slow progress when adding sequential identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, data-warehouse, etl

We have 8 million row table and we need to add a sequential id column to it. It is used for data warehousing.

From testing, we know that if we remove all the indexes, including the primary key index, adding a new sequential id column was like 10x faster. I still haven't figure out why dropping the indexes would help adding a identity column.

Here is the SQL that add identity column:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyTableSeqId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

However, the table in question has dependencies, thus I cannot drop the primary key index unless I remove all the FK constraints. As a result adding identity column.

- Is there other ways to improve the speed when adding a identity column, so that client down time is minimal?

or

- Is there a way to add an identity column without locking the table, so that table can be access, or at least be queried?

The database is SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what do you mean by "It is used for data warehousing." ?

Comment: I mean, is this table in the warehouse, or in a transactional system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new column to a table will acquire a Sch-M (schema modification) lock, which prevents all access to the table for the duration of the operation.

You may get some benefit from switching the database into bulk-logged or simple mode for the duration of the operation, but of course, do so only if you're aware of the effects this will have on your backup / restore strategy.

Comment: thx for the info. We are already using Simple Recovery Mode. So I guess there is no way to prevent lock on the table.

Comment: Performing queries on a half-modified table would seem like a bad idea - I think you're either going to have to settle for removing all the indexes, or stick with what you already have dsum.